# Built electron app only prints json to screen

Tags: electron

I just wrote my first Electron app. Now I'm trying to build it through `electron-packager`. My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "pixelcast",
  "productName": "pixelcast",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Wesley Peeters <wesley@youngones.works>",
  "description": "Caster",
  "license": null,
  "main": "./dist/electron/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "build:darwin": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=darwin node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "build:linux": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=linux node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "build:mas": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=mas node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "build:win32": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=win32 node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "build:clean": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=clean node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "build:web": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=web node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "dev": "node .electron-vue/dev-runner.js",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build",
    "pack:main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --config .electron-vue/webpack.main.config.js",
    "pack:renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --config .electron-vue/webpack.renderer.config.js",
    "postinstall": ""
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "nl.pixelservers.caster",
    "win": {
      "icon": "build/test.png",
      "target": [
        "portable"
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

this all works fine, but when I open the built app, this is my result:

[image]

How can I go about debugging an issue like this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*(This might be more of a "comment" than an answer but I couldn't add the detail and image in comment)*

It is hard to say without knowing how your project is structured. I use both `electron-packager` and `electron-builder`. The "dist" directory is solely for output so it is weird to me that you are referencing a script in that directory:

```
  "main": "./dist/electron/main.js",
```

Given my project structure (shown below), I have "main.js" at the same level as "project.json" so:

```
  "main": "main.js",
```

But maybe you have your project structured in a way which supports the way you are referencing "main.js"? . I'm using only `electron-packager` in the project below so no "dist" folder – I have the "release-builds" folder instead. My scripts for building look like this:

```
  "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite  --platform=darwin --arch=x64  --asar --prune=true --out=release-builds",
  "package-win": "electron-packager . --overwrite  --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --asar  --prune=true --out=release-builds"
```

[image]